# BDD parameters in a feature context?

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am writing a feature that will have scenarios with a parameter in common. 
The step would be something like this:

```
Given the user is viewing the book <bookIdAdress>
When ...
Then ...
Examples:
     | bookIdAddress |
     |    ...        |
     |    ...        |
```

I will have many scenarios like the above in my feature. And I want to test this feature with many books.

This same parameter would repeat for all scenarios of a feature. As far as my current knowledge of BDD is concerned, the only way is to keep putting the same examples in every single scenario. I was wondering if there was an option to have the Examples written once for the entire feature, or if I am completely wrong in doing it this way, what approach should I take?

I know I can use the Background tab to write a set up for the entire feature, but I don't know an option to just put the examples in a feature context only.

Comment: This feature is not available in any version of Gherkin that I'm aware of. Why would you want to do this? Can you give us a bit more context to help offer an alternative approach?

Comment: The example above has a parameter bookIdAddress, and all scenarios of the feature will have this parameter present. There will be many books to use as examples. I just thought that repeating tens of examples in every single scenario of a feature seemed a bit too redundant.

Comment: I see that perhaps it goes against the tool's purpose of making the scenarios readable by non developers, even though it may seem something obvious to us...

Comment: Yes, but what's the feature? How will behaviour change from book to book? Is the id the important piece of information, or does behaviour depend on some other property of the book? If you give us a concrete scenario or two it would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not share example tables in SpecFlow.  I tried by adding the table to the background as a way to hack it but it didn't work.

One option to consider is telling each Scenario to get data from the same excel file. Then you can share a data source as well as hide long tables of data.

http://www.specflow.org/plus/Excel/